# is there something in clojure like * or ** in python?

Tags: clojure

I have a vector and want to call a function in Clojure. The function accepts many arguments and I have vector.

For example:

```
 (defn f [a b] (+ a b))
```

and I have the vector:

```
  [1 2]
```

I can use apply:

```
  (apply f [1 2])
```

But can I call `f` in Clojure like in python?

```
  (f *[1 2]) .
```

---

My use case is that I need to `dissoc` some keys from a map. I want to call `(dissoc amap *keys)`, but it's not supported.

I could use `apply`

```
(apply dissoc (cons amap keys))
```

but it's not so convenient.

What's the best way to do this in Clojure?

Comment: What’s wrong with `apply`?

Comment: @user2219372 you could always build a macro that can read * and ** correctly but you should  probably just let go with these python syntax details and dive into learning the clojure way!

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you stated the benefits / difference you see in the python * operator over apply ?

Comment: I need to dissoc some keys from a map. I want to call (dissoc amap *keys),it's not supported. how to use apply? (apply dissoc (cons amap keys)). It's not convenient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As everyone else noticed, `apply` is the *exact* equivalent of Python's [arbitrary argument lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). In your use-case, given

```
(def a-map {1 2, 3 4, 5 6})
(def some-keys (range 5))
```

to `dissoc` `some-keys` from `a-map`

```
(apply dissoc a-map some-keys)
; {5 6}
```

---

My original solution also works

```
(reduce dissoc a-map some-keys)
; {5 6}
```

but only because `dissoc` can take its key arguments one at a time or all at once.

Comment: GREAT! It's what i want.

Comment: Just `(apply dissoc a-map some-keys)`. It's exactly what `apply` is for, and mirrors the `*keys` usage perfectly. `reduce` is fine too, in the specific case of `dissoc` (and many other cases), but `apply` is clojure's "version" of `*foo`, which is what OP asked about.